# Linode vs VPS.net vs other solutions

Tags: vps, linode

We have a large web application running on linode and part of it running on VPS.net. From our experience, Linode has been much more reliable. But we're recently decided to move the entire application to one provider only. So I'd like to know from your experience, which is a better VPS service and how do they compare to rackspace or slicehost?

The application uses lots of bandwidth and it's CPU intensive.

**Edit**

Thanks for the answers, I forgot to mention that RAM is also important

Comment: Just to let people reading this in the future know, Slicehost is dead.

Answer (score 3):

i've been happy with linode. their prices are decent, and anecdotal comparisons indicate the offer the best price/performance ratio.

if you aren't that picky about the distro you are using, you may also want to consider amazon EC2 which may provide growth and pricing flexibility you can't get with a traditional vps

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Linode is bit cheaper, but vps.net seems to offer better flexibility on pricing/new node. Last couple months vps.net has been bit unstable, especially London has suffered some SAN-related issues. What comes to prices rackspace is bit cheaper if you are thinking that you don't use bandwith so mutch as it goes by usage.

Personally i like vps.net as product and flexibility it offers, but tolerance for unstability starts to reach the end...